# Is there a term for a function whose sole purpose is to ignore one or more of its parameters?

Tags: function, functional-programming, terminology

Let's say that an API I'm using requires a callback function that takes two parameters, `apple` and `banana`.

An example in CoffeeScript:

```
example = (apple, banana) -> [...]
```

The function I *want* to use as the callback function takes only `banana` for its parameter:

```
myFunction = (banana) -> [...]
```

So I create a new function in order to use `myFunction` as the callback:

```
callback = (apple, banana) -> myFunction banana
```

Is there a proper term for this kind of function?

Comment: that sounds like the adaptor pattern to me, although I am not a patterns expert. maybe the function is simply called an adaptor too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When working with databases one uses the term "projection" for selecting and reordering list values (as parameters are). This is also typical in relational algebra (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28relational_algebra%29)), so I would apply the term here, too.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. That looks like the perfect word!